# Determining $a$ and $b$ when $\int_a^b\sin x\,dx$ is given as a Riemann sum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, trigonometry

> Determine $a$ and $b$ such that
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^n\sin\left(\left(2+\frac{3}{2n}\right)+\frac{3}{n}i\right)\cdot\frac{3}{n} = \int_a^b\sin x\;dx$$

[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2YoV.png)

$a$ should equal $2$, and $b$ should equal $5$. I don't understand how. If $\Delta x = 3/n$, shouldn't it be $f\left(a+\frac{3i}{n}\right)$? Where is the $\frac{3}{2n}$ coming from?

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: This is handled by the general Riemann sum $\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(t_i)(x_i-x_{i-1})$ where $t_i\in[x_{i-1},x_i]$. Remove the last term in your sum (this makes no difference as its limit is $0$) and the remaining sum matches $a=2,b=5,x_i=2+(3i/n),t_i=(x_{i-1}+x_i)/2$ so that the limit of sum is $\int_{2}^{5}\sin x\, dx$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you! Unfortunately, I'm still confused. Why is ti (xi−1 + xi)/2? I thought the general sum was f(xi), which would just be sin(2+3i/n). And what last term can I remove....?

Comment: As @ParmanandSingh mentioned, $t_i$ can be any value between $x_i$ and $x_{i+1}$. The extremes give Riemann lower and upper sums. The summation in question here is neither of them.

Comment: Referring to @ParmanandSingh 's comments, the last term has to be removed because the upper limit of summation should be $n-1$ to use the Riemann integral equation. This doesn't affect the summation because this term vanishes as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Comments are not intended for answering questions.  See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/dealing-with-answers-in-comments  Please post an answer instead of a comment.